# How to get particular string from the main string in android?

Tags: java, android

How do i get the string before second comma (,) in mainstring.

For Example:

```
String a="abcd,efg,hij,klm";
```

I want to get the output like `abcd,efg`

Comment: `split()` can be the magician to manipulate string. Play with it and get whatever result you want!

Comment: I really don't understand how no one downvoted and voted to close. This question **DOES NOT** demonstrate the minimal of minimal understanding or efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested this code, but you could use something like

```
private String GetFirstSplitN(String str,int n,String splitUsing)
{
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String []temp=str.split(splitUsing);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(sb.length>0)sb.append(splitUsing);
        sb.append(temp[i]);
    }

    return sb.toString();      
}
```

Then

```
String a="abcd,efg,hij,klm";
String str=GetFirstSplitN(a,2,",");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing:

```
String[] arr = a.split(",");     
String str = arr[0] + "," + arr[1];
```

Comment: this doesn't give `abcd,efg` ?

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question -_- What's with the upvotes? I'm editing now.

Comment: I don't like providing full solutions to this kind of questions.

Comment: yah i got the output thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the overloaded method [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) combined with the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method.

```
String b = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(',', a.indexOf(',')+1));
```

---

`a.indexOf(',', a.indexOf(',')+1)` returns the index of the second comma in the String.

Answer (score 0):

try as follows..

```
String[] splitedString = a.split(",");
String output = splitedString[0] + "," + splitedString[1];
```

Comment: I don't like providing full solutions to this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] split = a.split(",");
String beforeSecond = a[0] + "," + a[1];
String afterSecond = a[2] + "," + a[3];
```

Comment: I don't like providing full solutions to this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] array = a.split(",");
String value = array[0] + ","+ array[1];
```